# increasing app versionName using a compareTo

Tags: java, android, function, android-studio, compareto

I use an android application (we can call it "AppA") to update another one (we can call it "AppB").
The application "AppA" check the versionName of "AppB" and if it is lower then update start.

I check the versionName using the native function "compareTo". So this is my problem:
"AppB" versionName is 9.9 and the newest versionName is 9.10 but the update doesn't start because "compareTo" function result is "9.9 > 9.10".
Even if I use a new versionName like "10.9" or "9.100", always 9.9 is greater.

What should I put?

Comment: why not simply use the version code which will literally always be integers?

Comment: Why you are comparing versionName?, Instead of compare versionCode

Comment: It's an old application and we can't change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a version name of `9.9.1` to update it, since `"9.9".compareTo("9.9.1") < 0`.

You could as well use `9.90`, `9.91`, *etc.*, as every longer string is newer.

---

With the new update you should ship a new comperator with looks at every single component like:

```
int[] compOld = new int[3];
String[] split = versionOld.split(".");
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
    compOld = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
int[] compNew = new int[3]
...
return compOld[0] < compNew[0] || compOld[1] < compNew[1] || compOld[2] < compNew[2];
```

Or have a look at libraries for semantic versioning.

Comment: And for the newest? If I put 9.9.1 it goes well until 9.9.9 and then I will have the same problem

Comment: @img.simone you'd have to update your comparison strategy. If you keep it, you'll run into this issue every time the semantic ordering doesn't comply to the string order.

Comment: It's an old application and we can't change it right now

Comment: So you have to work around this limitation. I'd go with `9.900`, `9.901`, ..., `9.910`, `9.911`, ... to have a range long enough for future updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function to compare such version strings:

```
int compare(String version1, String version2) {
    String[] split1 = version1.split("\\.");
    String[] split2 = version2.split("\\.");  // split by dot delimeter
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(split1.length, split2.length); i++) {
        int number1 = Integer.parseInt(split1[i]);
        int number2 = Integer.parseInt(split2[i]);

        if (number1 < number2) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (number1 > number2) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (split1.length < split2.length) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (split1.length > split2.length) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```